# What about the usage of "any" and "no"?

Tags: negation, determiners, polarity-items, possessives

I taught my students that they can use *any* in questions with abstract countable nouns. Was I right? For example:

> Do you have any idea? (idea = abstract but countable)
>   Do you have any reason to do it? (= reason = abstract but countable)

And I also taught them that they can use *no* even with abstract countable nouns / countable nouns.

> I have no reason to do it.
>   I don't have any reason to do it.

I can use both of these interchangeably?

But what about

> I have no car.
>   I don't have a car.

Can I use both of these interchangeably too?  Or there is a difference between them?  Like *no* emphasizes the status of not having the thing?

> I don't have a car - a normal sentence
>
> Take your car, Tom.
>   But I have no car!! How many times do I have to tell you?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can see no problems with your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

You were technically correct (the best kind of correct!) - however, the usage of *any* and *no* is not limited to either abstract or countable nouns. All of the following sentences are correct:

> - Do you have any money? (uncountable, not abstract)
>   - No, I have no money.

---

> - Do you have any cars? (countable, not abstract)
>   - No, I have no cars.

---

> - Do you have any information? (uncountable, abstract)
>   - No, I have no information.

---

> - Do you have any relationships? (countable, abstract)
>   - No, I have no relationships.

Comment: And what about no? For example - I have no car ... by the way, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

Tom might well have been likely to say ***I have no car*** a century or more ago, but today he'd almost certainly say ***I don't have a car*** or ***I haven't got a car***.

When the "denial" applies to *multiple* items *(He has no teeth, I have no siblings, etc.)* the simpler construction remains perfectly idiomatic, but when denying the existence/ownership of even a *single* thing it comes across as lofty / literary / stylised / theatrical. [Here's a short Youtube cartoon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlgyDBbFQFs) poking fun at "figurative" ***I have no son!*** used as an overblown / affected reaction to one's son's shortcomings.

To a lesser degree, in conversational contexts people increasingly tend to avoid the simpler construction with *uncountable* referents. Thus the trend today is towards *I don't have any money* rather than *I have no money*...

[image]

...but note that some collocations, such as *I have no idea!* are firmly established, and not likely to change any time soon.